# Getting x,y of polygon in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, point, centroids

Is this the right way to get centroid x and y of a polygon. How do I get centroid x,y, of a polygon

```
layerName = "INTERIOR"
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
print layer.name()

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print f.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
```

Comment: Yes that is fine. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: No i mean that asPoint is use to get centroid of the polygon, polylin and point all can it use it. and this is the only right way? isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For similar questions that you are asked in your former posts, I think that you want to know how to visualize them (centroids) at the Map Canvas. In this case you need, e.g., one memory layer. Modifying your code to:

```
layerName = "INTERIOR"
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
print layer.name()

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'point',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

i= 0

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    feat = QgsFeature()
    pt = f.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    print pt
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt))
    prov.addFeatures([feat])
    i += 1

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it at the Python Console of QGIS, with a shapefile with the same name as yours, I got:

[image]

Now, they are visible.

Comment: how can i get the centroid of polygons in qgis3 using python console in it ?